# Updating Repeater on inputed value change

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

So i create popup Edit form, and i want to display connected rows in this popup also. For this i use Repeater with datasource and update datasource select comand each time when user opens Edit form:

Init of edit form:

```
   case "Edit":
   {
         var sourceKeyValue = DataUtils.GetInt64(grid.GetRowValues(e.VisibleIndex, grid.KeyFieldName));
         var resource = worker.ResourcePlanningViews.First(rpv => rpv.ID == sourceKeyValue);
         Session["VisibleIndex"] = e.VisibleIndex;
         Session["DateFrom"] = resource.DateFrom;
         Session["DateTo"] = resource.DateTo;
         this.userPlanings.SelectCommand = string.Format(@"Select [T0].id,
                            DateFrom, DateTo, 
                            [T0].Description, 
                            [T1].Name AS Project,
                            [T2].Name AS Company,
                            [T0].BookingPercentage
                            from[dbo].[WP_Topic_ResourcePlanning] as [T0]
                            Join WP_BaseData_Project as [T1] on[T0].ProjectID = [T1].id
                            Join WP_BaseData_Company as [T2] on[T1].CompanyID = [T2].id
                            where UserID in (
                            SELECT UserID
                              FROM[dbo].[WP_Topic_ResourcePlanning]
                                where id = {0})
                              and[T0].id != {0}
                              and (
                                [T0].DateFrom BETWEEN (@DateFrom) and (@DateTo)
                                or 
                                [T0].DateTo BETWEEN (@DateFrom) and (@DateTo))", resource.ResourcePlanningId);
                        grid.StartEdit(e.VisibleIndex);
                    }
```

Data Source:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="userPlanings" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebPortalConnectionString %>">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="DateFrom" SessionField="DateFrom" DefaultValue="2/22/2012" Type="String" />
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="DateTo" SessionField="DateTo" DefaultValue="7/22/2020" Type="String" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

After value in edit form changes i want to update repeater in pupup, for that i was trying to handle callback from ASPxCallbackPanel and update Session values with fresh date:

```
protected void HandleDateTimeCallback(object sender, CallbackEventArgsBase e)
    {
        var gridCntrl = this.gridResourcePlanningsCtrl.GridControl;
        var callbackPanel = (ASPxCallbackPanel)gridCntrl.FindEditFormTemplateControl("editFormPanelCtrl");
        int visibleIndex = (int)Session["VisibleIndex"];

        var sourceKeyValue = DataUtils.GetInt64(gridCntrl.GetRowValues(visibleIndex, gridCntrl.KeyFieldName));
        var resource = worker.ResourcePlanningViews.First(rpv => rpv.ID == sourceKeyValue);

        var dateFrom = (DateTime)this.GetCtrlValue("dtDateFrom", callbackPanel);
        var dateTo = (DateTime)this.GetCtrlValue("dtDateTo", callbackPanel);
        Session["DateFrom"] = dateFrom;
        Session["DateTo"] = dateTo;

        gridCntrl.StartEdit(visibleIndex);

    }
```

it isn't working.
Error message when i'm tryong to gridCntrl.StartEdit(visibleIndex):

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.'
```

Also i was trying to use Update Panel, but i had server Error "Type 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel' does not have a public property named 'Repeater'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to use List data source and update it each request

```
  repeater.DataSource = resources.Count() == 0 ? null : resources;
  repeater.DataBind();
```